# This proof of the chain rule looks arbitrary, yet at the same time doesn't, how to make sense of it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

A proof of the chain rule goes as follows:

Let $f=u\circ v$, so that $f(x)=u(v(x))$, $x\in \mathbb R$, and $v$ be differentiable at $x$ and $u$ be differentiable at $v(x)$. Then, by definition, the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{u(v(x+h))-u(v(x))}{h}$$

Let $k=v(x+h)-v(x)$, so that $v(x+h)=v(x)+k$. Thus:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{u(v(x)+k)-u(v(x))}{h}$$

Define:

$$g(t)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dfrac{u(v(x)+t)-u(v(x))}{t}, t\neq 0\\ 
u'(v(x)), t=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

This way, the following equality holds:

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=g(k)\cdot \frac{k}{h}$$

for any $h\neq 0$. Thus:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}g(k)\cdot \frac{k}{h}=\\ =\lim_{h\to0}g(k)\cdot \frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}$$

If $\lim_{h\to0}g(x)$ exists and since $v$ is differentiable at $x$:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}g(k)\cdot \lim_{h\to0}\frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}=u'(v(x))\cdot v'(x)$$

My issue with this is how any arbitrary value could have been assigned to $g$ at $0$ without making $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=g(k)\cdot \frac{k}{h}$ any less valid. Yet, the subsequent steps only hold if $g$ is specifically defined to be $u'(v(x))$ at $0$. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that the limit of $g$ exists for $h\to 0$.

I can't really point to exactly where the issue would be, but at the same time the process makes me feel uneasy, as if it were some arbitrary "trickery". It seems like it shouldn't work. I'd be glad if anyone could shed some light on it. Thanks.

Comment: $g$ is defined to be continuous at $h=k=0$, so $\stackrel{\ast}{=}$ works in$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}g(k)\cdot\frac{k}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}g(k)\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{k}{h}\stackrel{\ast}{=}g(0)\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{k}{h}.$$But we don't really need that last step; we just need to notice the value of $\lim_{h\to0}g(k)$.

Comment: @angryavian Except it's possible that sometimes $k=0$ where $h \neq 0$.

Comment: @J.G. my issue isn't with following the individual steps, but how a simple change of the definition of $g$, while not harming the equality established with the difference quotient of $f$, breaks the remainder of the proof. As to this specific point, I believe the continuity of $g$ at $0$ doesn't even need to be explicitly brought up? $\lim_{h\to 0}g(k)=u'(v(x))$ as it is; there's no need to state the intermediate equality $\lim_{k\to 0}g(k)=g(0)=u'(v(x))$. I'm not really sure if I understood what you were going for.

Comment: @angryavian No no, that's not true, it wasn't my intention at all to make it seem like that's what I was saying.

Comment: The important part is working out what $\lim_{t\to0}g(t)$ is, since that's what comes up as a factor in the calculation. The only way to write the result in terms of $g(0)$ instead is to prove it's $\lim_{t\to0}g(t)$. That's what the original text made unclear.

Comment: The fundamental reason for the chain rule is that $$\frac{u(v(x+h))-u(v(x))}{h}=\frac{u(v(x+h))-u(v(x))}{v(x+h)-v(x)}\cdot \frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}h,$$ and this would be the proof, if not for the problem when $v(x+h)=v(x),$ when you get a division by zero. So the proof needs a few tricks to work around those cases.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understand that, my issue is with how the accessory function $g$ could be defined to be anything at $v(x+h)-v(x)=0$ without breaking the equality you established, yet at the same time rendering the proof invalid if anything but $u'(v(x))$ is assigned to it. It feels uneasy to me because of how, even though that fundamental equality remains true, the rest of the proof doesn't follow if the accessory function is something other than $u'(v(x))$ at $v(x+h)-v(x)=0$. It seems conflicting.

Comment: $g$ must be continuous at zero, not just have a limit; otherwise the proof fails for example if $$ v(t) = \begin{cases} (t-x)^3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{t-x}\right) & t \neq x \\ 0 & t = x \end{cases} $$

Comment: Is the confusion that with that counterexample, we could have that $\lim_{t \to 0} g(t)$ exists but $\lim_{h \to 0} g(k)$ does not exist? The notation here is hiding the fact that $k$ is a function of $h$ (and not necessarily monotone).

Comment: If I understand the comments, the issue is isolated if we define $g(0)$ to be some number other than $u'(v(x))$ and see what goes wrong. What goes wrong is, the limit of the first quotient in Thomas Andrews' comment fails to exist as $h \to 0$ if the denominator is $0$ infinitely often in a neighborhood of $0$. That prevents us from deducing the limit of the product exists, resulting in an inconclusive argument.